# 'Add Account' doesn't display new options on MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql-workbench

I've linked MySQL to Heroku and am now trying to add user accounts through MYSQL Workbench. I'm using [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-mysql-connections-navigator-management-users-and-privileges.html#wb-users-and-privileges-accounts) and [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P7whjxMqYU4) as guides, but I don't see anything new after clicking Users and Privileges -> Add Account. After pressing on the 'Add Account' button on the Users and Privileges page, three buttons (add account, delete, and refresh) gray out and two buttons (revert and apply) become active, **but nothing else changes on my screen.** For reference, this is what I see after pressing Add Account: [image]

If I then press on Apply, I get a 'Save Account Changes' notification that tells me "It is a security hazard to create an account with no password. Please confirm creation of newuser'@'%' with no password."

Am I missing something? How do I get to the page where I can set the user account details?

Comment: Something went wrong there. You should see the list of existing users and a pane with user details. Check the log of MySQL Workbench (Help -> Show Log File) to see if there was an error that prevents the admin section to display properly.

Comment: After opening up workbench again after my computer went to sleep, I could see the proper options. But after restarting workbench, I'm having the same problem.

The only thing I could find that might relate to this issue from the Log File is:
"<object > key=ownercould not be resolved 10:01:31"

But to be honest, I'm not sure what I'm looking for in this log file. Is there anything in particular I should be looking for?

Comment: Look for lines starting with the error severity. But I think it would be better to report this issue as bug against Workbench (https://bugs.mysql.com), which allows better investigation. SO is not the right place for that.

Comment: I see. I couldn't tell if this was a bug or if I was just using Workbench incorrectly. Thank you for your time. I'll do just that.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. I didn't know there were already quite a number of bug reports for this issue. I'll take care that this gets fixed ASAP.